# Google Adwords conversion is not tracking

Tags: google-ads-api

I have a problem with Google Adwords conversion.
I've set up the tags and i can see with Google tag assistant, that the Global site tag is working, and when i checkout it shows correctly with the amount payed etc. in Google tag assistant, but nothings shows in Google Adwords.

I've set up the global tag in my header, between  and  and the conversion code on my order-confirmation.tpl page (In Prestashop 1.7.2.1)

[See picture from Google Tag assistant here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ0Oo.png)

What can the problem be, i've searched the entire web but i cant seem to find the problem.

Hope you can help me out! :-)

Comment: Hi Rasmus,

I don't have the answer but I am bit worried because I have to migrate to the new global tag with some clients. And it seems it does not work well. It interests me to know what happens.

Your implementation seems ok.

Did you call the Adwords support to investigate ?

Comment: @bastien Did you migrate your customers? Did you have problems with Cost/Conv rate on their accounts? Ours wetn up after the migration.